# Почему высота псевдоэлемента ограничена?

Tags: html, css

При отображении в браузере высота :after не превышает высоту hr. Почему?
Как получить необходимую высоту 5x?

```css
.description hr {
  width: 210px;
  height: 1px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  border: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent, #d3d4d7 25%, #D3D4D7 75%, transparent);
}

.description hr:after {
  content: "";
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #C4A676;
  border: 1px solid #C4A676;
}
```

```html
<div class="description">
  <hr>
</div>
```

Comment: Так у вас и так `::after` равен 5px по высоте.

Comment: Добрый день, не смог вчера с Вами пообщатся, чат неактивен еще!  Отображается в 1px, если выполнить код

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Достаточно добавить родительскому элементу `overflow: visible`:

```css
.description hr {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 1px;
  width: 210px;
  border: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent, #d3d4d7 25%, #D3D4D7 75%, transparent);
}

.description hr::after {
  content: "";
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: #C4A676;
  border: 1px solid #C4A676;
}
```

```html
<div class="description"><hr></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!